# How does one override the JQuery UI styles?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm using JQuery UI sortable, which seems to force the sortable elements to have display: block.

However, I would like these elements to have display: inline-block.

I've tried using this css:
    .item { display: inline-block !important; }

But it does not work (as evidenced by the computed styles in Chrome's console).

I've also tried using the following jquery statement:
    $('.item').css({display: 'inline-block'})

But that does not work either.

How can I override the JQuery UI styles?

Comment: by using a high specificity css selector.

Comment: Are you defining your CSS before or after you reference the `jquery-ui.css`?

Comment: I do not even reference jquery-ui.css anywhere, I am just using jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set float:none, which allowed the desired display style of inline-block to manifest.
Then I had to set vertical-align: top to make the elements align at their tops. The total css:

```
.item {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are targeting correct class?

I've this for my jquery-ui sortable, and it works perfectly.

```
#tabs .word-list li {
margin: 3px;
background-color: #FCFCFC;
padding: 7px 16px;
border-radius: 30px;
border-bottom: 2px solid #C7C7C7;
border-right: 2px solid #B1B1B1;
display: inline-block;
}
```

I also don't load jquery-ui-css file, I believe it is bloated. And I roll out my style anyways for these elements, might not be your case.

Try targeting more specifically. Like I do. id->class.

Also you can try including jquery-ui-css file before your own custom styles.

Comment: I am definitely targeting the correct class, with a high level of specificity. I also have never loaded the jquery-ui-css file, I am only using the jquery-ui.js file. So I'm not sure why its not working on my end...

Comment: @user1050268 Make jsfiddle than :)

Comment: Good suggestion! It turns out that my issue is below the level of jquery ui and is in fact an issue I am having with html/css in general.
As in, I am trying to have the elements in the following jsfiddle float so that the fourth item is flush with the left border of its container (instead of wrapping directly beneath the third item) http://jsfiddle.net/emg6x/   Do you know how this can be done without resorting to creating divs that are just row containers?

Comment: Note: I'm seeking that above described float /clear behavior in cases where I cannot predict how many items will be in the container, and what their sizes will be.

Comment: @user1050268 maybe you should use packery instead of jquery ui sortable. take a look: packery.metafizzy.co